# Não consigo executar comandos fora da janela do vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

opa,queria saber pq n consigo executar meu bot fora do vscode,tipo eu quero pegar uma coordenada mais ela só funciona dentro do vs code,se eu sair e entrar no jogo e apertar a tecla q adicionei pra pegar a coordenada não funciona,se eu fazer um macro completo tbm,ele liga dentro do vscode,mais se eu for pro jogo ele n funciona,só esta funcionando dentro da janela do vs code,se for fora n funciona não era pra estar assim alguém consegue me ajudar?